# difference between cells and children in a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

Take a simple table, like:

```
<table id="fu">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I get the top element "fu" and then I get to the 0,0 cell one of two ways.

```
fu.children[0].children[0].cells[0]
```

or

```
fu.children[0].children[0].children[0]
```

I understand the difference between children and childNodes, but cells and children seem to be identical. If I look at them in the debugger I see:

```
 fu.children[0].children[0].
   ...
   cells: HTMLCollection(2) [th, th]
   childElementCount: 2
   childNodes: NodeList(5) [text, th, text, th, text]
   children: HTMLCollection(2) [th, th]
   ...
```

What is the difference and should I be using .cells or .children or doesn't it matter? It doesn't seem to matter but I worry that there might be situations where they differ that would break my code.

thanks

Comment: Please use `document.querySelectorAll` and `document.querySelector`.

Answer (score 3):

`cells` and `children` are not the same.

`cells` only includes `th` and `td`, whereas `children` can include any [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

If you run this in Chrome:

```html
<html>
<body>

<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>CellOne</td>
    <td>CellTwo</td>
    <script>console.log('hello world');</script>
    <td>CellThree</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  let concat = '';

  let row0_children = document.getElementById("table1").rows[0].children;
  concat = '>>> Summary: \n' + 'Length of row_0.children = ' + row0_children.length + ', including:\n';
  for (const v of row0_children) concat += '-' + v.innerText + '\n';
  console.log(concat);

  let row0_cells = document.getElementById("table1").rows[0].cells;
  concat = '>>> Summary: \n' + 'Length of row_0.cells = ' + row0_cells.length + ', including:\n';
  for (const v of row0_cells) concat += '-' + v.innerText + '\n';
  console.log(concat);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

---

---

You will get the following output:

```
>>> Summary: 
Length of row_0.children = 4, including:
-CellOne
-CellTwo
-console.log('hello world');
-CellThree

>>> Summary: 
Length of row_0.cells = 3, including:
-CellOne
-CellTwo
-CellThree
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the only child elements a table row can have are cells, there is no practical difference between the two when used on a `tr` element.

The `children` property applies to all elements in the DOM, but is from a newer specification that `cells` so isn't supported on some ancient and obsolete browsers.